# How to set a number of Projects visible in RStudio's top-right pane?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to specify how many projects are visible in the top-right pane in Rstudio? Default option is 10, however I would like to change this to a higher number.

Edit: Screen added.[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot here?

Answer (score 2):

Can't be (easily) done.

RStudio seems to have a hard limit of 15, and there's a comment in the code about setting the max visible according to the screen size, and that 15 is up to 10 local projects and 5 shared projects:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/cef7e679b05d9e92003a30847757f57fd30ee94c/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/application/ui/ProjectPopupMenu.java#L209

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/cef7e679b05d9e92003a30847757f57fd30ee94c/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/application/ui/ProjectPopupMenu.java#L275

So if you want more, you'll have to file an enhancement request with RStudio (or edit the Java code and build it yourself...)